# Three.js displacementMap does not affect lighting, only vertices

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using Three.js to apply a displacement map to a simple plane. The displacement applies successfully, but the lighting is wrong, as if all the normals remain unchanged. The result is a surface with the right shape that's lit as if it were flat.

**displacement map:**

[image: displacement map]

**result:**

[image: plane with displacement map, but bad normals]

How can I fix this to properly change the lighting?

Here is the relevant bit of code:

```js
// shortened from actual code - please excuse any small typos

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(500, 250);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(100, 100, 100);

var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.2);

scene.add(light);
scene.add(ambient);

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, 2, 1, 20000);

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 1000);
geometry.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = textureLoader.load('circlemap.png');

material.displacementScale = 20;
material.displacementMap = texture;

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(mesh);

// ... later
renderer.render(scene, camera)
```

*edit:* when I set `flatShading: true` in the material, the normals are updated correctly, but look bad (because of the flat shading):

[image: displacement map working properly with flat shading]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to have to pass a `normalMap` along with your `displacementMap`.

[See this demo](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_displacementmap), when `normalScale = 0` it's the equivalent of having no normalMap, and you can see that the reflections don't follow the displacement, only the default topography. However, when normalMap is 1, then the reflections do respect the displacement.

You need to generate a normalMap.

Comment: True, turns out this is the intended behavior. Using a displacement+bump map now which still looks bad but is OK for my purposes. More discussion here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/19677